# Why did Hamas kidnap children?

Tags: israel, terrorism, hamas, 2023-israel-hamas-war

According to the [NBC news the hamas terrorists intentionally targeted children](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/investigations/top-secret-hamas-documents-show-terrorists-intentionally-targeted-elem-rcna120310)
to take them hostage.

"kill as many people as possible, seize hostages and quickly move them into the Gaza Strip."

They even succeeded of kidnapping
[a six month old baby.](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12623335/Six-month-old-baby-named-Ariel-17-Britons-missing-dead-Hamas-attacks.html)

[or, according to BBC a nine-month old one.](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67064742)

I dont understand this tactic. why kidnap young kids and a baby? they're even more vulnerable than "regular" hostages, doesn't make more sense to kidnap more "resilient" people?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the perspective of Hamas, hostage-taking can have multiple functions.

One is that they can be traded back for others seized by Israel.

A second is that it potentially curtails the appetite of Israel for relatively random missile attacks, since they may consume hostages in the process.

A third is that potentially adds to the psychological effect of the assault, in ways that don't just involve killing.

A fourth is that hostages can potentially experience things from the other side of the fence, unfiltered, which may ultimately be beneficial to Hamas - and probably isn't politically beneficial for Israel.

These functions are all possibly fulfilled by seizing children and babies, or by seizing families which include children and babies.

Moreover, children are also less likely to pose a physical threat to the captors, and may have a pacifying effect on any parents or other adults held with them.

Finally, the option to take hostages including children probably allows Hamas to mobilise more militants, avoids moral injury to those it has, and avoids needless inefficiencies in the field.

Some militants may be willing to kill indiscriminately, but others would probably prefer to avoid executing children or unarmed adults, and avoid the dilemmas that would ensue from that aversion if hostage-taking were not allowed.

For example, if no hostages can be taken, do you execute unarmed parents then leave the children stood there as orphans? Or if taking adult hostages, do you try and tear parents away from their children, which is liable to cause struggle compared to coercing the whole family unit to go? The solution when the adults are posing no threat seems to be to seize them all as prisoners.

Comment: And kidnapping children brings more media attention which introduces public pressure on Israel to get them released.